# Select same data-set at different date ranges in a single query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

what I am trying to do is performing a query that has multiple results of the same query by just editing only a where clause.

The goal is to query a result of the same dataset in different date ranges, but instead of performing multiple separated queries, having one single query that queries the tables X times (depending on the selected date ranges).

For example:

```
SELECT database_one.users.firstname,
       database_one.users.lastname,
       COUNT(*) AS "Total"
FROM database_two.announcements
INNER JOIN database_one.prospect_evaluations ON database_one.prospect_evaluations.announcement_id = database_two.announcements.id
INNER JOIN database_one.users ON database_one.prospect_evaluations.user_id = database_one.users.id
WHERE (database_two.announcements.deleted_at IS NULL
       AND (database_two.announcements.archived_at IS NOT NULL
            AND database_two.announcements.crmstate != 'Scartata'))
  AND (database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) /* THIS IS THE DATE RANGE TO EDIT IN THE SUBQUERY */
GROUP BY database_one.prospect_evaluations.user_id
ORDER BY database_two.announcements.id DESC
```

What I'd like to have is something like this, in pseudo-sql:

```sql
SELECT database_one.users.firstname,
       database_one.users.lastname,
       COUNT(*) AS "Total",
       /* PSEUDO-SQL START { */
       COUNT(*) WHERE (database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS "1 Month"
       COUNT(*) WHERE (database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) AS "3 Months"
       COUNT(*) WHERE (database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) AS "6 Months"
       COUNT(*) WHERE (database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AS "1 Year"
       /* } PSEUDO-SQL STOP */
FROM database_two.announcements
INNER JOIN database_one.prospect_evaluations ON database_one.prospect_evaluations.announcement_id = database_two.announcements.id
INNER JOIN database_one.users ON database_one.prospect_evaluations.user_id = database_one.users.id
WHERE (database_two.announcements.deleted_at IS NULL
       AND (database_two.announcements.archived_at IS NOT NULL
            AND database_two.announcements.crmstate != 'Scartata'))
GROUP BY database_one.prospect_evaluations.user_id
ORDER BY database_two.announcements.id DESC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pseudo-SQL is surprising close to the **standard** SQL clause `FILTER`, which has only been implemented by Postgres but unfortunately not by MySQL:

```
SELECT database_one.users.firstname,
       database_one.users.lastname,
       COUNT(*) AS "Total",
       -- Standard SQL: FILTER
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS "1 Month"
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) AS "3 Months"
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) AS "6 Months"
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AS "1 Year"
...
```

The good news is that in MySQL you can use equivalent (and standard SQL as well) `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT database_one.users.firstname,
       database_one.users.lastname,
       COUNT(*) AS "Total",
       -- Standard SQL: COUNT(CASE ...)
       COUNT(CASE WHEN database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
               THEN 1 END) AS "1 Month"
       COUNT(CASE WHEN database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
               THEN 1 END) AS "3 Months"
       COUNT(CASE WHEN database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
               THEN 1 END) AS "6 Months"
       COUNT(CASE WHEN database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
               THEN 1 END) AS "1 Year"
...
```

or the more compact but non-standard `SUM()` that uses the implicit conversions of boolean values (TRUE and FALSE) to 1 and 0:

```
SELECT database_one.users.firstname,
       database_one.users.lastname,
       COUNT(*) AS "Total",
       -- Non-standard SQL: SUM(boolean expression)
       SUM(database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
          ) AS "1 Month"
       SUM(database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
          ) AS "3 Months"
       SUM(database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
          ) AS "6 Months"
       SUM(database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
          ) AS "1 Year"
...
```

---

By the way, you could use aliases for the various tables in the `FROM` clauses so the query becomes shorter and usually more readable.

Also the `announcements.id` is ambiguous in the `SELECT` orr `ORDER BY` clause after a `GROUP BY`, because it is not in the group by list. Use `MIN()` or `MAX()` or some other `ORDER BY` instead.

The query with aliases - and assuming you choose the `SUM()` solution from above:

```
SELECT u.firstname,
       u.lastname,
       COUNT(*) AS "Total",
       -- Non-standard SQL: SUM(boolean expression)
       SUM(a.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS "1 Month"
       SUM(a.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) AS "3 Months"
       SUM(a.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) AS "6 Months"
       SUM(a.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))  AS "1 Year"
FROM database_two.announcements  AS a
JOIN database_one.prospect_evaluations  AS pe
    ON pe.announcement_id = a.id
JOIN database_one.users  AS u
    ON pe.user_id = u.id
WHERE a.deleted_at IS NULL
  AND a.archived_at IS NOT NULL
  AND a.crmstate <> 'Scartata'
GROUP BY pe.user_id
ORDER BY MAX(a.id) DESC ;
```

Comment: I love the `CASE` way! Thank you, you saved my life!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch (note that I changed the GROUP BY and removed the ORDER BY since it was not clear to me what the query was suppose to mean)

```
SELECT database_one.users.firstname,
       database_one.users.lastname,
       COUNT(*) AS "Total",
       COUNT(CASE WHEN database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) THEN 1 END) AS "1 Month",
       COUNT(CASE WHEN database_two.announcements.archived_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) THEN 1 END) AS "3 Month",
       ...
FROM database_two.announcements
JOIN database_one.prospect_evaluations 
    ON database_one.prospect_evaluations.announcement_id = database_two.announcements.id
JOIN database_one.users 
    ON database_one.prospect_evaluations.user_id = database_one.users.id
WHERE database_two.announcements.deleted_at IS NULL
  AND database_two.announcements.archived_at IS NOT NULL
  AND database_two.announcements.crmstate != 'Scartata'
GROUP BY database_one.users.firstname,
         database_one.users.lastname
```